# How i can Validate Purchase and get Purchase info(to create receipt in my app) in future after order finished

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments

I have to validate purchase every time user login to my app . is there api call to check if finished purchases succeed and valid.

example: user purchased item . and after a month i want to check if he payed on this product ?

1. which api call a need to do?
2. which info i need save in my DB for that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am still didn't found answer anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [REST API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/) returns a link that you can use to look up a payment. For Adaptive Payments, use the Pay Key to look up the payment.

Instructions for [verifying a mobile payment](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/mobile/verify-mobile-payment/) may also be relevant.

If you need to be notified when a payment happens, you might also consider subscribing to a webhook or IPN notification.

Comment: If every time i want to validate purchase i am making "GetExpressCheckoutDetails" api call and i check that i get in response :
          "CHECKOUTSTATUS": "PaymentActionCompleted"
and that there is TRANSACTIONID property with value.  Is it enough.